# Pandas - Determine How Many Days Recorded in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data formatted like this (where Timestamp is in datetime format)

```
Timestamp           Location
7/24/2017 14:55:19  Location_A
7/24/2017 15:09:16  Location_B
7/25/2017 14:05:45  Location_B
7/26/2017 8:34:40   Location_A
7/26/2017 8:45:56   Location_B
7/26/2017 9:34:11   Location_A
7/26/2017 10:03:14  Location_B
7/27/2017 9:26:14   Location_B
7/27/2017 9:37:26   Location_B
7/31/2017 10:22:46  Location_A
7/31/2017 10:59:02  Location_B
```

Each time a timestamp occurs with either Location_A or Location_B, then that means that location was open that day. I'd like to count the number of days each location is open so that the output looks like this:

```
Location    Days_Open
Location_A  3
Location_B  5
```

I know I need to use groupby and likely a lambda function, but I'm not having much luck. I appreciate any help

Comment: what is the data type of Timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Timestamp` is a string,

```
df['Timestamp'].str.split(' ', n=1).str[0].groupby(df['Location']).nunique()
```

The first part, `df['Timestamp'].str.split(' ', n=1).str[0]`, extracts the date part of the string. Then, it is grouped by location so that we count unique dates separately by location.

If `Timestamp` is a timestamp column, the left part will simplify to `df['Timestamp'].dt.date`. The full expression then will be:

```
df['Timestamp'].dt.date.groupby(df['Location']).nunique()
```

Comment: Both of these solutions give (4, 7) for me; not (3, 5).

Comment: @fuglede it was the wrong aggregation, should have been `.nunique`. Should be good now

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
(pd.crosstab(df.index.date, df.Location) > 0).sum()
```

With your data:

```
In [64]: df
Out[64]:
                       Location
Timestamp
2017-07-24 14:55:19  Location_A
2017-07-24 15:09:16  Location_B
2017-07-25 14:05:45  Location_B
2017-07-26 08:34:40  Location_A
2017-07-26 08:45:56  Location_B
2017-07-26 09:34:11  Location_A
2017-07-26 10:03:14  Location_B
2017-07-27 09:26:14  Location_B
2017-07-27 09:37:26  Location_B
2017-07-31 10:22:46  Location_A
2017-07-31 10:59:02  Location_B

In [65]: (pd.crosstab(df.index.date, df.Location) > 0).sum()
Out[65]:
Location
Location_A    3
Location_B    5
dtype: int64
```

If `Timestamp` isn't your index, either replace `pd.index.date` with `df.Timestamp.date`, or set it as the index by using `df.set_index('Timestamp')`.

A different approach could be

```
df.groupby(['Location', pd.Grouper(freq='D')]).size().unstack(0).count()
```

and the same thing with `pivot_table` would be

```
df.pivot_table(index=df.index.date, columns='Location', aggfunc='size').count()
```

In both cases, the `size` is a bit silly; any constant function (such as `lambda _: 1`) would do as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach, groupby date and count

`df.groupby(by=df['Timestamp'].dt.date).agg(count=('Location', 'value_counts')).reset_index()['Location'].value_counts()`

```
Location_B    5
Location_A    3
Name: Location, dtype: int64
```